# C# Regex for Username

Tags: c#, regex

im searching for a regex for my Username System in C#

It is structured as follows:

(Firstname_Lastname)

The first letter is capital A-Z

then small at least three characters a-z

then an underscore (_)

then first letter capital A-Z again

and small at least three characters a-z

Can somebody help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We expect people to show what they've tried, rather than just asking for things to be done for them. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular

Comment: Also, please edit your question for the appropriate tag... is it `C#` or is it `javascript`... and what does `html` have to do with it?

Comment: Try adding what you have tried, and any username examples that the responder can try

Comment: I apologize for my rude behavior, next Question it will be better. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code it will help you: `(^[A-Z][a-z]{2,}_[A-Z][a-z]{2,})`

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(^[A-Z][a-z]{2,}_[A-Z][a-z]{2,})";
        string input = @"Firstname_Lastname
fi_na
Fi_na
fi_Na
Fir_Name
Firs_name
firs_Name";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the demo: https://regex101.com/r/8RUcaG/1

Comment: Thanks man! It works very good. 
that's exactly what I'm looking for :)